# Building a Dashboard Layout as Fragment programmatically

Tags: android, fragment, dashboard, android-viewpager

I'm building my first Android app, main view and all subviews are based on a dashboard layout so I'm trying to reuse the DashboardLayout from the GoogleIO 2011.

I managed to get it working with the `ViewPager` using `FragmentPagerAdapter` (since `DashboardLayout` is designed as Fragment). I created three xml as `DashboardLayout` with 6 icons each and works perfectly.

Now it's time to make everything dynamic: I need to create `DashboardLayout`s programmatically according to remote data (json).

At the moment I'm calling the instantiation of the `DashboardFragment` in the main activity like this:

```
...

ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, DashboardFragment.class.getName()));

...
```

in the `DashboardFragment` class I have:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
}
```

and basically this is the fragment_dashboard xml file:

```
<com.google.android.ui.widget.DashboardLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:id="@+id/firstbutton"
        style="@style/DashboardButton"
        android:text="@string/btn_first"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_first" />
    ...
</com.google.android.widget.DashboardLayout>
```

Now instead of returning fragment_dashboard inflated view I think I need to Instantiate DashboardLayout and add to it buttons according to the downloaded json data. But I don't know how.

Ideas?

Comment: Try this link: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10544602/set-webview-loadurl-programmatically-that-is-in-fragment-class]